# Expo React Native App with Push Notifications - How to Handle Different BundleIDs for Public App Store and Private Self Serving Store?

Tags: ios, push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have a React Native app built with Expo that currently supports push notifications on iOS using APNS. The app is built in expo.dev for production, and I download the IPA for distribution to a private self-serving store of another company we're doing the app for.

The challenge I'm facing is that the private store has a different bundleID compared to the one used in our configuration (Apple Developer / Expo), and the push notifications are configured with the Expo bundleID.

As a result, when push notifications are sent, they are linked to our Expo/App Store bundleID and cannot communicate with the apps installed from the private store due to the different bundleID.

Error : "Could not find APNs credentials for com.xxxx.yy.zzzzzz (@company/project). You may need to generate or upload new push credentials."

com.xxxx.yy.zzzzzz is the private store bundleId

I'm seeking guidance on how to address this issue, Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

PS : I don't want it to work for both, just for the private store.